# Trying to count the emoji's from text

Tags: python, emoji

I'm trying to count emoji's in textlines. These are tweets.
I tried different codes, but they all return empty.

Eg:

## emoticons

```
def split_count(text):
    emoji_counter = 0
    data = regex.findall(r'\X', text)
    for word in data:
        if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI_ENGLISH for char in word):
            emoji_counter += 1
    return emoji_counter      

split_count_udf = F.udf(split_count, IntegerType())

kick_twitter_count = kick_twitter.withColumn("num_emoji", adv.emoji_counts["full_text"])
```

Error I got:

```
Error: AttributeError: module 'advertools' has no attribute 'emoji_counts'
```

emoji_dict stays empty as well:

Any ideas? It would help me a lot!

Comment: why do you thinkg `adv.emoji_counts` attribute exists ?

Comment: Well, that's the problem. It's not working and I don't find the reason for that. So it seems I have to adjust something in the code above?

Comment: What do you mean "don't understand" ? `emoji_counts ` **does not exists**, it is same as write `adv.bmskdfmlksmlf()` it does not exists. Why did you wrote that method name ? Why did you thought it exists ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner. When I do emoji_dict.keys, it returns the list of keys including emoji_counts. So, what am I misunderstanding then? And if it doesn't exist, can you help me to get a count of emoji's in another way?

Comment: I don't even see a `emoji_dict` variable, and `adv` is a package. Sorry I can't help at all, regarding the few information I see.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to extract the emojies first to load the dictionary:

```
import advertools as adv
texts = ['I am grinning ','A grinning cat ','hello!  ', 'Just text']
emoji_dict = adv.extract_emoji(texts)
emoji_dict['emoji_counts']
[1, 1, 5, 0]
```

Ref:
https://advertools.readthedocs.io/en/master/advertools.emoji.html

Comment: If I run this, it works. But somehow it doesn't work on the column.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't work on the column". You just need to put whatever text contains the emojis in the list, in this case called "texts" and it should work exactly like in the answer. It will return another list with the count of emojis of each element in the list "texts".

Comment: I did this to make an extra column with the counts:

texts = kick_twitter['full_text']
emoji_dict = adv.extract_emoji(texts)
kick_twitter = kick_twitter.withColumn('num_emoji', emoji_dict['emoji_counts'])

TypeError: Column is not iterable

Comment: texts has to be a list, try texts=[ kick_twitter['full_text'] ]

Comment: Then I get this: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: that seems to be another issue unrelated to the emoji count. You may need to raise another question but try to share the code, traceback of the error, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help!